# Setting relative path in a WebAPI project for static files

Tags: asp.net-web-api, web-config, url-routing

Given a relative path for an asset in html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css">
```

How can I specify a root folder (or base path) in my WebAPI project that does not point at the project directory but at some folder under that directory (e.g. I do NOT want ProjectDir/css/styles.css, I want ProjecDir/SomeFolder/css/styles.css). I expect that this might be possible using RouteConfig, but I'm unsure how.

Should the explanation lend some clarity: I have an external front-end (Git) repo for UI development that runs on a simple node server, I have added this repo to the WebAPI project so that it can serve the static files in production.

**I want to avoid having to modify relative paths when deploying, or copy and pasting files between directories.**

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that works, just appendend './' to the asset paths.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, where did you append ./ ?

Comment: On your script src paths. <script src="./yourpath">